# Connection error issue from client on NuxtJS development server

Tags: docker, nginx, npm, vagrant, nuxt.js

When spa NuxtJS is started with `npm run dev` command, the screen display on the browser is normal, but the following error occurs when checking the development console of chrome.
`GET http://localhost:38849/sse net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OqbK.png)
This indicates an error connecting sse to localhost.
I don't understand why this refers to localhost.
I have the following settings listed in nuxt.config.js.

```
server: {
  port: 3000,
  host: '0.0.0.0',
},
```

package.json is as follows.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxt/content": "^1.3.2",
  "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.11.0",
  "nuxt": "^2.13.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
  "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
  "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2",
  "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
  "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
  "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
  "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
  "eslint": "^7.2.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
  "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^1.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.4",
  "jest": "^26.0.1",
  "prettier": "^2.0.5",
  "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
}
```

This Nuxt server is a docker container and is reverse proxyed from a nginx container and use docker-compose.
Nginx config is this.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myhost;

    location / {
        proxy_redirect                      off;
        proxy_set_header Host               $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout          1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
        proxy_pass   http://app:3000;
    }

}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  #--------------
  # Web Server
  #--------------
  web:
    image: nginx:alpine
    container_name: 'web'
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ./docker/api:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/web/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./docker/web/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - ${WEB_PORT}:80
    networks:
      - app-net

  #--------------
  # Frontend App
  #--------------
  app:
    container_name: app
    build: ./docker/app
    expose:
      - ${FRONT_PORT}
    #privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ./docker/app:/var/www/app
      - /var/www/app/node_modules
    #stdin_open: true
    #command: npm run serve
    #command: ash
    tty: true
    networks:
      - app-net
```

network bridge setting omitted.
these are running on Vagrant on Windows 10.

Is this a development server hot reload issue?
Please lend me your knowledge.

Comment: This issue only occurs on the development server and is resolved with `nuxt start`.